Modify Selector Parent Lot/ Serial Nbr to Add Filter in Materials Screen (AM300000)
Hi I want to modify the Parent Lot/ Serial Nbr in the materials screen to only show selector records where the value is greater than 0 in remaining quantity.
Selector screen
I’ve tried to modify the selector using these approaches below and it still shows selector records with remaining quantity 0.00.
 [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)][PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<AMProdItemSplit.qtyRemaining.IsGreater<decimal0>>), "Qty Remaining is zero")]
protected virtual void _(Events.CacheAttached<AMMTran.parentLotSerialNbr> e) { }

[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Replace)]
[PXDBString(INLotSerialStatus.lotSerialNbr.LENGTH, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Parent Lot/Serial Nbr.", Enabled = true, FieldClass = "LotSerial")]
  [PXDefault("")]
[PXSelector(
   typeof(Search2<AMProdItemSplit.lotSerialNbr,
                InnerJoin<AMProdItem,
                    On<AMProdItem.prodOrdID, Equal<AMProdItemSplit.prodOrdID>,
                    And<AMProdItem.orderType, Equal<AMProdItemSplit.orderType>>>>,
                Where<AMProdItem.orderType, Equal<Current<AMMTran.orderType>>,
                    And<AMProdItem.prodOrdID, Equal<Current<AMMTran.prodOrdID>>,
                    And<AMProdItemSplit.qtyRemaining, Greater<decimal0>>>>>),
    typeof(AMProdItemSplit.lotSerialNbr),
    typeof(AMProdItemSplit.qty),            // Display: Total Quantity
    typeof(AMProdItemSplit.qtyComplete),    // Display: Quantity Completed
    typeof(AMProdItemSplit.qtyScrapped),    // Display: Quantity Scrapped
    typeof(AMProdItemSplit.qtyRemaining),   // Display: Quantity Remaining
    SubstituteKey = typeof(AMProdItemSplit.lotSerialNbr)
)]
protected virtual void _(Events.CacheAttached<AMMTran.parentLotSerialNbr> e)
{
}

Please let me know what I am missing, thank you!!

You need to use PXRestrictor attribute, and you don't need to replace all of the attributes.
QtyRemaining is an unbound field, you need to use this calculation in the restrictor.
    [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Merge)]  // Note the Merge instead of Replace
    [PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<SubNotLessThanZero<AMProdItemSplit.qty, 
            Add<AMProdItemSplit.qtyComplete, AMProdItemSplit.qtyScrapped>>, Greater<decimal0>>), 
        "Remaining Quantity is 0.")] 
    protected virtual void _(Events.CacheAttached<AMMTran.parentLotSerialNbr> e) { }

I tested it on 24R1.

Hi @zoltan I tried this approach and this does not filter and does not show any records in the selector

Did you remove the quantity filter from the selector?

Yes I removed my original logic and then tried the pxrestrictor

Ok, please show the current attributes of the field, and I will take a look.

this is the original atributes of the selector: [PXDBString(INLotSerialStatus.lotSerialNbr.LENGTH, IsUnicode =true, InputMask ="")]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Parent Lot/Serial Nbr.", FieldClass = "LotSerial")]

I have updated my answer.

thanks alot I was not aware qtyremaining was not persisted in the database
